# Retriving list items

Tags: caml

I am retrieving my list items using the current time, but my code is retrieving nothing. Please anyone help me out on this.

Here is my CAML code:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ScheduleTime'/><Value Type='Choice'>"+hr+"</Value></Gt></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
```

Comment: The leading "" and the finishing "10" in your CAML query have no sence at all. Furthermore, we don't see what value the variable hr has. I suggest you to check this quick starts on CAML: http://joshmccarty.com/2012/06/a-caml-query-quick-reference/ and http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/caml-query-tutorial-for-sharepoint.html

Comment: That may have been in part format issues, I have cleaned up the post

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Time values in a choice field so might be the issue of some date format i guess.

Could you please try first getting result using CAML query builder through UI?

[CAML Query Builder](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/)

It lets you easily build CAML queries through UI. You can trial and error with various values and once you get desired output, you can use that in your code.